# random secret key generator using fixed seed java

Tags: java, key-generator

I want to generate a secret key (128 bit) based upon some predefined seed value .

Currently i am using javax.crypto.KeyGenerator (AES) to generate key using secureRandom .

How can i pass my own seen rather than using secureRandom object .

code i am currently using :

//

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128,SecureRandom random); // 128 bits key size
key = kgen.generateKey();
```

//

Thank You ..

Comment: Why would you need that? If you need the way to obtain the same key from the same password or similar non-random input, you should look at PBKDF2 or some other key-derivation function.

Comment: Actually i want to generate key , whose seed is derived from some fixed value .

Comment: Just "generate" the key bytes as you wish and use `SecretKeySpec` directly. You *can* implement your own `SecureRandom` and pass it into the `KeyGenerator` but you have no real control on how the key generator uses that random object and how many random bytes it takes out of it to generate a key.

Comment: thnx sir . I implemented SecureRandom .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the seed of the `SecureRandom`.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
random.setSeed(1000L);
```

When testing this i did notice that to get consistant results you had to recreate the `KeyGenerator` if you changed the seed at any time.